# SocketException 10054

Tags: исключения, .net

Добрый день, я пишу маленькое клиент-серверное приложение. К серверу могут подключаться сразу несколько клиентов. Для рассылки сообщения всем клиентам я использую этот код:

```
// IPEndPoints - List<IPEndPoint>, где я храню клиентские IPEndPoint
// packet - byte[] с данными
for (int i = 0; i < IPEndPoints.Count; ++i)
    server.Send(packet, packet.Length, IPEndPoints[i]);
```

На сервере чтобы получать сообщения использую это:

```
//packet - byte[] для данных
//endPoint - IPEndPoint
packet = server.Receive(ref endPoint);
```

Но, когда один из клиентов отключается, я все-равно пытаюсь отправлять ему сообщения и получаю исключение `SocketException` с кодом `10054`. Сам вопрос: как мне понять, какой именно из клиентов отключился? Как мне получить `IPEndPoint` этого клиента, чтобы удалить его из списка `IPEndPoints`? Я думал, что нужный `IPEndPoint` будет в переменной `endPoint` (передана с параметром `ref`), но когда срабатывает исключение, переменная остается нетронутой.

Учитывая просто комментарии мастера программирования добавляю следующую информацию:

Я знаю, как ловить исключения в C#, мне не понятно, как получить `IPEndPoint` отключенного клиента

Comment: Заключите отправку данных в блок `try ... catch` и обрабатывайте ошибку.

Comment: Какой тип имеет переменная `server`?

Comment: То есть вот так у Вас не получится (это псевдокод) ?  

    for (int i = 0; i < IPEndPoints.Count; ++i) {
        try {
            server.Send(packet, packet.Length, IPEndPoints[i]);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            IPEndPoints.deleteItem(i); // метод List для удаления элемента
            i--;
        }
    }

Comment: AlexeyM, server -  System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient

Comment: ReinRaus, извиняюсь, я наверное плохо объяснил. Строчка
<pre><code>server.Send(packet, packet.Length, IPEndPoints[i]);
не кидает исключений. Исключение кидает строчка:
    packet = server.Receive(ref endPoint);

Comment: Хотел был поднять вопрос. Имею ту же траблу, что и автор и не пойму как ее разрешить. Пытаюсь отправить (BeginSendTo) сообщение по несуществующему адресу УДП сокетом, выскакивает эта ошибка и сокет закрывается в EndReceive.

Answer (score 1):

Это старый баг в WinSock. После создания сокета нужно сделать так:

```
var sioUdpConnectionReset = -1744830452;
var inValue = new byte[] {0};
var outValue = new byte[] {0};
socket.IOControl(sioUdpConnectionReset, inValue, outValue);
```

Не знаю, что это за магия (нагуглил где-то), но помогает!

Узнать, какой именно клиент отключился, как я понял, нельзя, да и не нужно — с этим фиксом исключений не будет, а клиента можно будет кикнуть по таймауту.

Под линуксом бага нет, а кроме того, этот фикс сам бросает исключение. Чтобы работало на всех платформах я просто оборачиваю этот кусок в try-catch, ну или придумайте свое, более элегантное решение.