# C# UDP отправка сообщения на несуществующий адрес вызывает SocketException 10054

Tags: c#

Всем привет.
К сожалению я не знаю как поднимать старые темы, в частности вот эту [SocketException 10054](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/242423/socketexception-10054).
Я пишу тестовый клиент сервер, учусь работать с УДП. У меня возникла аналогичная проблема как по ссылке выше и интерес скорее теоретический нежели практический.
Но я попробую изложить ее более подробно.
Есть открытый UDP канал на сервере. Он принимает сообщения с любого адреса через BeginReceiveFrom / EndReceiveFrom. 
Имеется список адресов - обычный List IPEndPoint - ов. 
Этот список только пополняется, то есть если клиентское приложение или подключение было закрыто, то адрес не удаляется из списка.

Когда кто либо присылает сообщение на серверный UDP сокет, сервер пытается переслать его всем адресатам из списка.
Естественно, что если адресат не существует, то должна выскакивать ошибка отправки, НО вместо нее ошибка происходит в методе EndReceiveCallback, а именно на строке с _socket.BeginReceiveFrom(...), после чего сокет закрывается.

Вот код для наглядности:

```
    private void OnReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        EndPoint ep = _remoteEndPoint;
        int rLenght = 0;
        try{
            if (_isClosed == 0) { rLenght = _socket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref ep); }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { CatchedException(ex); }

        try {
            if (rLenght > 0){
                byte[] receive = _readBuffer;
                byte[] pack = NetProtocol.GetPacket(ref receive);

                if (pack != null) { ReceiveAction?.Invoke(this, pack); }
            }

            if (_isClosed == 0){
                ep = _remoteEndPoint;
                _socket.BeginReceiveFrom(_readBuffer, 0, _readBufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ref ep, OnReceiveCallback, ep);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { CatchedException(ex); }
    }

    public override void Send(byte[] data, object sendParam = null)
    {
        IPEndPoint ep = null;
        try{
            if (!_remoteEndPoint.Equals(Any)){ ep = _remoteEndPoint; }
            else{ ep = sendParam as IPEndPoint; }

            if (ep != null){
                if (_isClosed == 0){
                    _socket.BeginSendTo(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, ep, OnSendCallbackTo, null);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            SocketException sex = ex as SocketException;
            if (sex != null) { NetLogger.Log("SEX " + sex.ErrorCode + ", " + sex); }
            else { NetLogger.Log("SOCKET: " + ex); return; }
        }
    }
```

В функции CatchedException() происходит закрытие сокета, если ошибка была типа SocketException, но как видно из кода функция вызывается только из ресив метода. В сенд методе ошибка просто пишется в лог и ничего ломаться по идее не должно.
Собственно вопрос, почему ловится ошибка именно в Receive методе, а не в Send ?

**Уточнение** Сокет рвет соединение в любом случае, даже если вместо ручного закрытия при ошибке просто логгировать.

Что попробовал дополнительно:

- если адрес удалять из списка перед закрытием клиента - все замечательно работает.
- думал, может есть какая то магическая зависимость от закрытия сокета ранее подключаемого клиента, но если внести перед стартом фейковый адрес, то ошибка снова воспроизводится.

**Уточнение 2**
Путем создания двух сокетов на стороне сервера (чистого ресивера и чистого сендера) удалось решить проблему разрыва соединения. На клиенте соответственно так же задается 2 адреса - для отправки на Receive канал сервера, а прием только с sender канала. Но считаю такое решение костыльным и **вопрос оставляю открытым**, поскольку при таком раскладе даже нативный дотнетоский UDPClient валится от этой проблемы и фактически работа UDP сокета имеет неконтролируемую зависимость от адреса доставки.

Comment: `Естественно, что если адресат не существует, то должна выскакивать ошибка отправки,` - нет. UDP это отправка без подтверждения. И отправляющая сторона не знает, получил ли адресат сообщение или нет (если он не соизволит сам об этом сообщить).

Comment: Тогда совсем не понятно, почему вообще рвется соединение.

Comment: Да, гарантии доставки нет и никто сообщать о приеме не обязан. Но в большинстве случаев если слушателя с той стороны нет формируется icmp пакет вроде "хост не достижим" или "порт не достижим", после его прихода любая операция с сокетом вызовет ошибку. Не знаю как с c# но в других языках это само по себе не приводит к закрытию сокета. ошибку надо обработать и проигнорировать. если она возникла на отправке - повторить отправку. И для отправки стоит использовать не тот же сокет что для приема, что бы прием не давал ошибок

Comment: В таком случае Вы предлагаете делать отдельно некий UDP listener и UDP sender на серверной стороне ? Можно попробовать как вариант, но хотелось бы конечно обойтись одним универсальным классом, а не тремя.